# Jquery doesn't get the unique ID after an ajax post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been struggling to find solution to this problem for 3 weeks now, I have an html table with data populated through mysql query, and I update the database through jquery ajax post method, there is no problem during the initial load of the page, I can get all the unique id and validate it through a bootstrap modal, however, the problem is after the first post method when it redirect back to the table, all of the unique id are converted on the id that was first posted..so all of the data extracted was base on that id, It should not be that way since I want to target a unique id through the 'click to pay cash advance' button..can anyone help me where the glitch is?

here is the code for my html table

```
    $cashAdvances = array(); $x = 0;
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    $fromStart = $_POST['fromStartDepartment'];
    $toEnd = $_POST['toEndDepartment'];

<div id="tableDepartment">  

    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="<?= 
    'departmentTable'; ?>" >
    <tr bgcolor = "#2c3e50">
           <th><font color="white"> Company Id</th>
           <th><font color="white">Department</th>
           <th><font color="white">Name</th>
           <th><font color="white">Date Covered</th>
           <th><font color="white">Cash Advance</th>
           </tr>
       <?php $data = array(); 
                 $dateCovered = $fromStart.'to'.$toEnd;
           ?>
           <?php while($result = 
          mysqli_fetch_array($resultQueryDepartment)): ?>




                <?php $cashAdvances[] += $result['company_id']; 
                   $data[] = array('id'=> $result['company_id'],
                                    'department'=>$result['department'],
                                   'name'=>$result['name'],
                                   'dateCovered' =>$dateCovered,
                       'cashAdvanceCredit' => 
             $resultAttendancePayroll['salary'],
                       'duration' => 'Weekly'

                   );
                   $json_data = json_encode($data);
                   $myDir = 'JSON'; 

                   if(!file_exists($myDir)){
                       $oldmask = umask(0);//helpful when used in linux 
                       mkdir($myDir, 0777);
                   }



      file_put_contents($myDir.'/resultsCashIssuanceDepartment.json', 
      $json_data);
            ?>
    <?php while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($resultQueryDepartment)): ?>
    <tr></tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    <a data-stateName="<?= $result['company_id']; ?>" id="susubukan"><button 
    type="button"  id="modalIndividualOnDepartment"  value="<?= 
    $result['company_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary edit_data"   data-
    toggle="modal" data-target="#modalIndividualDepartment"
                <?php
                if(($resultCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment) || 
     ($resultFullyPaidIndividualOnDepartment == '0')){
                    echo 'disabled';
                }else{
                    echo '';
                }
                  ?>  
                >Click to Pay Cash Advance</button></a>
    </td></tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is the modal for validation

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalIndividualDepartment" tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Individual Payment</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="dataOnDepartment">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript to process the data on modal

```
$('a[data-stateName]').on('click', function(){
var ID = ""; 
ID = $(this).attr("data-stateName");
//console.log(ID);

$('#modalIndividualDepartment').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
//var cashAdvanceCredit = $("#cashAdvanceCredit").attr("value");
//console.log(cashAdvanceCredit);
                $.getJSON('JSON/resultsCashIssuanceDepartment.json', 
function(data){


                //var ID = checkID;

                var output = '<table class="table table-bordered table-
                              condensed"><tr>';
                output +='<th id="highlight"><font color="white">
                          <center>Employee ID</center></font></th><th 
                          id="highlight"><font 
                          color="white"><center>Name</center></font></th>
                           </tr>';
                output += '<tr>';
                          $.each(data, function(key, val){
                          if(val.id == ID){
                output += '<td><center>' + idier(val.id)+val.id + 
                          '</center></td>';
                output += '<td><center>' + val.name + '</center></td>';
                           var department = val.department;
                           var dateCovered = val.dateCovered;
                           var explodeDateCovered = dateCovered.split("to");
                           var name = val.name;
                           var duration = val.duration;
                           var fromStart = explodeDateCovered[0];
                           var toEnd = explodeDateCovered[1];
                           var cashAdvanceCredit = val.cashAdvanceCredit;


                output += '</tr></table>';
                output += '<form method="post" 
                           id="formSubmitDepartmentIndividual"><div 
                           class="form-group row"><div 
                           class="col-xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6">
                           <input type="text" 
                           name="cashAdvanceDepartmentOneTimeModal" 
                           id="cashAdvanceModalDepartment" 
                           class="form-control" placeholder = "less than '+ 
                           cashAdvanceCredit +'">
                           </div></div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="date" 
                           name="datecashAdvanceAllOneTimeModal" 
                           id="modalDepartmentDate" class="form-
                           control" value = "'+today+'" readonly></div>
                           </div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="function"  
                           class="form-control" value = "" ></div></div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="employeeID"  
                           class="form-control" value = "'+ ID +'" ></div>
                           </div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="type"  
                           class="form-control" value = 
                           "cashAdvanceIndivualDepartment" ></div></div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="department"  
                           class="form-control" value = "'+department+'" >
                           </div></div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="fromStart"  
                           class="form-control" value = "'+fromStart+'" >
                           </div></div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="toEnd"  
                           class="form-control" value = "'+toEnd+'" ></div>
                           </div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="name"  
                           class="form-control" value = "'+name+'" ></div>
                           </div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input 
                           type="hidden" name="duration"  
                           class="form-control" value = "'+duration+'" >
                           </div></div>';
                output += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-
                           xs-3"></div><div class="col-xs-6"><button 
                           type="button" class="btn btn-
                           default" data-
                           dismiss="modal">Close</button>&nbsp<input 
                           type="submit" 
                           value="submit" 
                           id="submitModalDepartmentIndividual" 
                           name="btnSubmit" 
                           class="btn btn-primary"></div></div></form>';

                    var x = cashAdvanceCredit;
                    $('#dataOnDepartment').html(output);
                    var value = $('#cashAdvanceModalDepartment').val();
                    console.log(value);
                    //disable submit button if cash advance is empty
                    $('#submitModalDepartmentIndividual').prop("disabled", 
                    true);
                    $('#cashAdvanceModalDepartment').keyup(function(event){
                    var input = $('#cashAdvanceModalDepartment').val();
                    var Exp = new RegExp(input);

                    if(event.which != 8 && 
                    isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))){

                    $('#submitModalDepartmentIndividual').prop("disabled", 
                    true);
                    }else if(($('#cashAdvanceModalDepartment').val() == '') 
                    || (Number($('#cashAdvanceModalDepartment').val()) > 
                    Number(cashAdvanceCredit)) || 

              (/^\s*$/.test($('#cashAdvanceModalDepartment').val().trim())))
      {


           $('#submitModalDepartmentIndividual').prop("disabled", true);
                       }
                    else 
        if(($("#cashAdvanceModalDepartment").val().replace(/ /g,'').length 
        != 0)){


              $('#submitModalDepartmentIndividual').prop("disabled",false);

                    }
                    else{

      $('#submitModalDepartmentIndividual').prop("disabled",false);
                    }
                    console.log(cashAdvanceCredit);
                    console.log($('#cashAdvanceModalDepartment').val());
                    });

                   }
                });
                //marker

      $('#formSubmitDepartmentIndividual').on('submit',function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                            url:"ajaxPaymentProcessor.php",
                            method:"POST",

        data:$('#formSubmitDepartmentIndividual').serialize(),
                            success: function(data){
                          //$('#modalIndividualDepartment').hide();
                            $('#formSubmitDepartmentIndividual')[0].reset();

         $('#modalIndividualDepartment').modal('hide');
                                $('#tableDepartment').html(data);
                                //$(".objects-list").html(data["html"]);
                            }
                      });

                  });       

             });

            }); 
          });
```

Here is the landing page that will process the ajax call

```
$type= $_POST['type'];
$cashAdvances = array(); $x = 0;
$employeeID = $_POST['employeeID'];
$prettyEmployeeID = idier($_POST['employeeID']).$_POST['employeeID'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];

<?php if($type == 'cashAdvanceIndivualDepartment'): ?>

            <?php 
            //scope variable
            $date = $_POST['datecashAdvanceAllOneTimeModal'];

            $department = $_POST['department'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $fromStart = $_POST['fromStart'];
            $toEnd = $_POST['toEnd'];

            $cashAdvanceCredit = 
 $_POST['cashAdvanceDepartmentOneTimeModal'];
            //------end scope variable------//



            if($queryCashAdvanceResult){

            $output = '<h4><center>Cash Advance of <b><font 
                       color="red">'.$cashAdvance.' PHP</font></b> was made 
                       for <b><font color="red">'.$employee['first_name'].' 
                     '.$employee['last_name'].'</font></b></center> </h4>';
            $output .= '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" 
                        id="departmentTable">
                        <tr bgcolor = "#2c3e50">
                        <th><font color="white"> Company Id</th>
                        <th><font color="white">Department</th>
                        <th><font color="white">Name</th>
                        <th><font color="white">Date Covered</th>
                        <th><font color="white">Cash Advance</th>
                       </tr>';
            $data = array();




            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($resultQueryDepartment)){




                $cashAdvances[] += $result['company_id'];
                $data[] = array('id'=> $result['company_id'],
                    'department'=>$result['department'],
                    'name'=>$result['name'],
                    'dateCovered' =>$dateCovered,
                    'cashAdvanceCredit' => 
                    $resultAttendancePayroll['salary'],
                    'duration' => 'Weekly'
                 );
                $json_data = json_encode($data);
                $myDir = 'JSON';

                if(!file_exists($myDir)){
                    $oldmask = umask(0);  // helpful when used in linux 
                   server
                    mkdir($myDir, 0777);
                }

             file_put_contents($myDir.'/resultsCashIssuanceDepartment.json', 
             $json_data); 



                $output .='<tr>
                           <td><p 
  id="subukanUlit">'.idier($result['company_id']).$result['company_id'].
               '</p></td>
                     <td>'. $result['department'].'</td>
                     <td>'.$result['name'].'</td>
                     <td>'.prettydate($fromStart)." to 
                     ".prettydate($toEnd).'</td>
                      <td>
                        <a data-stateName="'.$result['company_id'].'">
               <button type="button"  id="modalIndividualOnDepartment"  
              value="'.$result['company_id'].'" class="btn btn-primary 
            edit_data"   data-toggle="modal" data-
            target="#modalIndividualDepartment"
                             '.
         ((($resultCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment) || 
         ($resultFullyPaidIndividualOnDepartment == 
          '0'))?'disabled':'').'>Click to Pay Cash Advance</button></a>
                           </td>
                </tr>';
                $x++;
            }
            $output .='</table></div>';
            echo $output;
            ?>

            <?php }?>

            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if($type == 'cashAdvanceDepartmentOneTime'): ?>
                <?php 
                             $department = $_POST['department'];
                             $duration = $_POST['duration'];
                             $fromStart = $_POST['fromStartDepartment'];
                             $toEnd = $_POST['toEndDepartment'];
                             $cashAdvance = 
                             $_POST['cashAdvanceDepartmentOneTime'];
                             $employeeID = $_POST['employeeID'];
                             $employeeID = 
                             unserialize(base64_decode($employeeID));
                             $dateOfPayment = 
       $_POST['dateCashAdvanceDepartment'];
                             $counter = sizeof($employeeID) - 1;
                             $starter = '';
                             for( $starter = 0 ; $counter >= $starter ; 
            $starter++ ){
                                 $id = $employeeID[$starter];
                                 $id = idier($employeeID[$starter]).$id;
                                 $idNotProcessed = $employeeID[$starter];
                                 //select from employee_profile
                                 $queryName = "SELECT * FROM 
       employee_profile WHERE company_id = '$idNotProcessed' ORDER BY
                                               id DESC LIMIT 1";
                                 $resulQueryName = $db->query($queryName);
                                 $resultName = 
       mysqli_fetch_array($resulQueryName);
                                 $name = $resultName['first_name']." 
       ".$resultName['last_name'];
                                 //end select from employee profile
                                 //select department
                                    $queryDepartmentCashAdvance = "SELECT 
        employee_profile.id, employee_profile.company_id, 
        company_profile.department
                                                                    FROM 
         employee_profile INNER JOIN company_profile WHERE 
         employee_profile.company_id = company_profile.company_id
                                                                    AND 
          employee_profile.company_id ='$idNotProcessed' ";
                                    $resultQueryDepartmentCashAdvance = $db-
          >query($queryDepartmentCashAdvance);
                                    $resultDepartmentCashAdvance = 
          mysqli_fetch_array($resultQueryDepartmentCashAdvance);
                                    $department = 
          $resultDepartmentCashAdvance['department'];
                                 //end select department
                                 //CHECK FOR EXISTING RECORD
                                 $queryExistingRecord = "SELECT * FROM 
           cash_advance WHERE company_id = '$id' AND date >= '$fromStart'
                                                         AND date <= 
           '$toEnd'";
                                 $resultExistingRecord = $db-
           >query($queryExistingRecord);
                                 $existingRecord = 
         mysqli_fetch_array($resultExistingRecord);

                                 if(empty($existingRecord)){
                                     //INSERT INTO CASH ADVANCE ONE TIME
                                     $queryCashAdvanceDepartment = "INSERT 
        INTO cash_advance(company_id, name, department,advance_payment, 
         date, duration)
                                     VALUES('$id', '$name', 
       '$department','$cashAdvance', '$dateOfPayment', '$duration')";
                                     $resultQueryCashAdvanceDepartment = 
        $db->query($queryCashAdvanceDepartment);
                                     //END INSERT INTO CASH ADVANCE ONE TIME
                                 }
                                 //END CHECKING FOR EXISTING RECORD

                             }
                             //------query department-------//
                             $queryDepartment = "SELECT 
      attendance_payroll.company_id, attendance_payroll.name, 
       attendance_payroll.date_identifier, company_profile.department
                             FROM attendance_payroll INNER JOIN 
       company_profile ON company_profile.company_id = 
       attendance_payroll.company_id
                             WHERE company_profile.department = 
      '$department' AND attendance_payroll.date_identifier >='$fromStart' 
       AND attendance_payroll.date_identifier <= '$toEnd'
                             GROUP BY attendance_payroll.company_id ORDER BY 
       attendance_payroll.company_id ";
                             $resultQueryDepartment = $db-
       >query($queryDepartment);
                             //-----end query department----//
                             $output = '<h4><center>Cash Advance of <b><font 
     color="red">'.$cashAdvance.' PHP</font></b> was made for <b><font 
     color="red">ALL</font></b></center> </h4>';
                             $output .= '<table class="table table-bordered 
     table-condensed" id="departmentTable">
      <tr bgcolor = "#2c3e50">
           <th><font color="white"> Company Id</th>
           <th><font color="white">Department</th>
           <th><font color="white">Name</th>
           <th><font color="white">Date Covered</th>
           <th><font color="white">Cash Advance</th>
           </tr>';
                             //$data = array();
                             //$dateCovered = $fromStart.'to'.$toEnd;

                             while($result = 
               mysqli_fetch_array($resultQueryDepartment)){
            //check cash advance per individual if already existing
                                 $employeeID = 
              idier($result['company_id']).$result['company_id'];
                                 $queryCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment = 
          "SELECT * FROM cash_advance WHERE duration = 'Weekly'
                                 AND company_id = '$employeeID' AND date >= 
            '$fromStart'
                                 AND date <= '$toEnd'";

       $resultQueryCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment = $db-
        >query($queryCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment);
        $resultCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment = 
        mysqli_fetch_array($resultQueryCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment);
                                 //end checking
    //check if already fully paid and not be qualified for cash advance
        $queryFullyPaidIndividualOndepartment = "SELECT * FROM 
        attendance_payroll WHERE company_id = '$employeeID'
                                 AND date_identifier >='$fromStart' AND 
        date_identifier <='$toEnd'
                                 AND payment_status = '1'";
                                 $resultQueryFullyPaidIndividualOnDepartment 
          = $db->query($queryFullyPaidIndividualOndepartment);
                                 $resultFullyPaidIndividualOnDepartment = 
           mysqli_num_rows($resultQueryFullyPaidIndividualOnDepartment);
                                 //end checking
                                 $output .='<tr>
                           <td><p 


 id="subukanUlit">'.idier($result['company_id']).$result['company_id'].'</p>
   </td>
                           <td>'. $result['department'].'</td>
                           <td>'.$result['name'].'</td>
                           <td>'.prettydate($fromStart)." to 
 ".prettydate($toEnd).'</td>
                           <td>
                           <a data-stateName="'.$result['company_id'].'">
   <button type="button"  id="modalIndividualOnDepartment"  
  value="'.$result['company_id'].'" class="btn btn-primary edit_data"   
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalIndividualDepartment"
                             '.
  ((($resultCashAdvanceByIndividualOnDepartment) || 
  ($resultFullyPaidIndividualOnDepartment == '0'))?'disabled':'').'>Click to 
   Pay Cash Advance</button></a>
                           </td>
                </tr>';
                                 $x++;
                             }
                             $output .='</table></div>';
                             echo $output;
                             ?>
                                <!-- VALIDITY OF PAY BUTTON FOR ALL -->
                                    <?php 
                                          $queryAttendancePayrollCompare = 
    "SELECT attendance_payroll.id, attendance_payroll.company_id, 
     attendance_payroll.name, company_profile.department  

     FROM attendance_payroll INNER JOIN company_profile WHERE 
     attendance_payroll.company_id = company_profile.company_id

    AND date_identifier >= '$fromStart' AND date_identifier <= '$toEnd' AND 
    company_profile.department = '$department'

    GROUP BY attendance_payroll.company_id ORDER BY 
    attendance_payroll.company_id";
    $resultAttendancePayrollCompare = $db-
    >query($queryAttendancePayrollCompare);

   $resultAttendancePayrollCompareCount = 
   mysqli_num_rows($resultAttendancePayrollCompare);

   $queryCashAdvanceCompare = "SELECT * FROM cash_advance WHERE duration = 
  'Weekly' AND department = '$department'
                                                                      AND 
   date >= '$fromStart' AND date <='$toEnd' GROUP BY company_id ORDER BY 
   company_id";
                                          $resultQueryCashAdvanceCompare = 
   $db->query($queryCashAdvanceCompare);
                                          $resultCashAdvanceCompareCount = 
   mysqli_num_rows($resultQueryCashAdvanceCompare);

                                      ?>
                          <!-- END VALIDITY OF PAYMENT BUTTON FOR ALL -->
                             <?php

                        ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Please help and many thanks :)

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: Too much code, narrow the issue down a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer folks,

I need to include all of the function even the hidden modal on the landing page because once it was refreshed, what it was reading was not on the same page anymore instead, the data on the landing page..

Thanks anyway :)